Rango como argumento en una función
En Google Apps Script quisiera hacer una función a la que le paso un rango de celdas y el código en hexadecimal de un color, la función me ha de devolver el número de celdas que tienen el color pasado como argumento.
 function contarCeldasColorbis(rango,colorHex) {
  // Convierte el rango en un objeto de rango
  const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  rangoCeldas = hoja.getRange(rango);
  //const rangoCeldas = hoja.getRange("N7:N");
  //const valores = rango.getValues();
  
  // Convierte el código de color hexadecimal a minúsculas (por consistencia)
  //const colorTarget = colorHex.toLowerCase();
  let contador = 0;

  // Recorre cada celda del rango y cuenta las que coinciden con el color especificado
  for (let i = 1; i <= rangoCeldas.getNumRows(); i++) {
    for (let j = 1; j <= rangoCeldas.getNumColumns(); j++) {
      const colorCelda = rangoCeldas.getCell(i, j).getBackground();
      if (colorCelda.toLowerCase() === colorHex) {
        contador++;
      }
    }
  }

  return contador;
}

Si introduzco el rango en la función funciona, pero al ponerlo como argumento no hay manera.
Realizo la llamada a la funcion,     =contarCeldasColor("N7:N","#f9cb9c")
Gracias.
Jose.
